# Extracting line segments by points (in ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting, extract

I have a feature containing line objects. In addition, I have the file with the *approximate* start- and endpoints of the segments I want to extract. Each start- and endpoint pair share the same ID.

As an output, I'd like to have the full line feature split into segments / parts by the point feature. Ideally, an additional column in the line feature shows the ID of the according point segment. I've added a sketch to illustrate.

[image]

The tool "[Split Line at Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm)" does not suffice, since it simply results in a cut up line with no information of the segments.

Can anybody point me in the right direction without using ArcPy?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the code you've tried, any error messages when you run it, and detail on what does or doesn't happen when you run it

Comment: There is no request for code in OP. Why close?

Comment: Most of output segments have 2 points, how do you want to handle this?

Comment: @FelixIP the assumption (maybe incorrect) is code is desired due to `arcpy` tag

Comment: I removed the arcpy tag. I was open to arcpy suggestions, but  havent tried any code (since I wouldn't know where begin). Can it be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you are showing a real example of your data it is clear you are processing a river network, which you should of mentioned as that will attract different responses. Also you are showing scenarios not previously mentioned which is that two points (e.g. blue) are separated by multiple line segments, this changes everything.

Instead of being "local" processing of geometries you are in fact asking a network tracing solution. This can be done with network analyst and a little bit of model builder. There are other specialist software design to process site data along river networks such as ArcHydro or RivEX, although they may not specifically link pairs of sites. Your solution probably lies in using network analysis.

Comment: I'm very sorry for over-simplying my problem..and for not stating that I had river data. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of steps that can be done manually or automated in model builder are these:

1. Dissolve the Points on ID to create MultiPoint Features.
2. Create a point midway between each set of two points, "Feature To Point"
3. "Spatial Join" the midpoint ID to the Lines.
4. Join the complete Point attributes to Lines, based in ID.

Comment: I like the idea of dissolving to create multi-points, I always forget you can do that!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It only works in very simple cases. As soon as two segments overlap or the line is heavily curved, this approach will provide false results. I've updated the image with the real life case to illustrate the complexity.

Comment: As you are now discovering @Ratnanil it always pays to provide real data not some abstraction of it as that is what we only have to go by...

Comment: @Hornbydd: Is this always true? Here, you're probably right. But the idea of SO *is* to provide a **minimal** example, right?